# Best (performance-wise) way to store timestamp in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have a java application that records timestamps for events. The problem I faced was that there are often a large volume, and having java calculate and format the datetime was too costly for performance. I eventually setup the mysql field to automatically use the current_timestamp. This had a huge performance gain in my app.

The big problem I've encountered is that half our users have mysql servers that are hosted elsewhere, and the timezone settings are different and may not be changed.

I need to find a way to generate the timestamp on either side, but in a way that's not a hit to performance easily converted into the correct timezone, if needed.

I've considered using a unix epoch instead, since that doesn't need any formatting when I'm inserting the data, it should be less of a performance problem.

Is there a better way?

Comment: An epoch is relatively fast to generate, it's a timezone neutral instant in time than can easily be compared with other instants (less than, more than), and for relatively close times arithmetic is simple. Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>   (...) The [current] time zone can be set on a per-connection basis
>   [with the [time_zone](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) system variable].

I would recommend sticking to the built-in `TIMESTAMP` type. Time zone for the current session can be set by issuing (e.g. for UTC+2) `SET SESSION time_zone = '+2:00';`.